# Less not loaded with package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less, storybook

I build npm package to use in other react project,
the components are working byt without less style

inside storybook its working with less
here is the package
npm i @linkne/react-storybook-antdesign

and here is storybook parameters
main.js

```
const path = require('path');
// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = {
  "stories": ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|mdx)'],

  "addons": ["@storybook/addon-links", "@storybook/addon-essentials", "@storybook/addon-interactions"],
  "framework": "@storybook/react",
  core: {
    builder: "webpack5"
  },    
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './components/App.js',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$|jsx/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'less-loader',
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                javascriptEnabled: true,
                            }
                        }
                    }
                
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-storybook",
  "version": "0.2.5",
  "description": "Storybook design systems with AntDesign",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.1.1",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^1.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.2.0",
    "antd": "^4.21.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "min-indent": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/cli": "^5.1.11",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.9 ",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "less-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0"
  }
}
```

and this is the package.json from the different project, webpack its exacly the same

```
{
  "name": "argoportal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://bitbucket.org/linkmobility/argoportal.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/linkmobility/argoportal#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-card": "^1.20.2",
    "@ant-design/pro-components": "^1.1.5",
    "@ant-design/pro-descriptions": "^1.10.71",
    "@ant-design/pro-form": "^1.67.1",
    "@ant-design/pro-layout": "^6.38.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-list": "^1.21.59",
    "@ant-design/pro-skeleton": "^1.0.5",
    "@ant-design/pro-table": "^2.74.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@linkne/react-storybook-antdesign": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
    "activity-detector": "^3.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.20.2",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "highcharts": "^10.1.0",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.4.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.21",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-confirm-alert": "^2.8.0",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-date-range": "^1.4.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-datetime-picker": "^3.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-icon-base": "^2.1.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-select": "^5.2.2",
    "react-switch": "^6.0.0",
    "react-timezone-select": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "umi": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "webpack-watch-server": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack": "^5.70.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```